# Return node with most connections to other nodes having a specific property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following relationships in my message graph:

```
(m:Message)-[:ORIGINATED_AT]->(i:IP)-[:IN_NETWORK]-(n:Network)
```

I am trying to find the IPs and Networks sending the most messages with category = 'spam'.

I have tried the following query:

```
// IPs sending the most spam:
match (ip:IpAddress)--(m:Message)
where toLower(m.category) contains 'spam'
with ip, size(()-[:ORIGINATED_AT]->(ip)) as volume
ORDER BY volume DESC LIMIT 10
match (ip)--(net:Network)
return ip, net
```

but it seems to find "networks that have sent the most messages with at least one spam message", but I want "networks that have sent the most spam". Also, the query returns less than the 10 expected results.

I removed the message variable to get the IPs sending the most messages, and this seems to work as expected:

```
// IPs sending the most messages:
match (ip:IpAddress)
with ip, size(()-[:ORIGINATED_AT]->(ip)) as volume
ORDER BY volume DESC LIMIT 10
match (ip)--(net:Network)
return ip, net
```

**How can I modify my query to correctly count only the relationships where the related (m:Message) has category:'spam'?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, you are just overcomplicating it a little. You just need the count aggregation od every message that contains "spam" per IP address.

```
MATCH (ip:IpAddress)--(m:Message)
WHERE toLower(m.category) contains 'spam'
RETURN ip, count(m) AS spam_messages
ORDER BY spam_messages DESC LIMIT 10
```

To use `size()` in this situation replace `count()` with a different aggregation function, `collect()`, which puts the elements in a list or collection instead of counting them. Then use `size()` to return the number of items in the list. This approach would be useful if you needed the actual elements themselves for some kind of post processing afterwards.

```
MATCH (ip:IpAddress)--(m:Message)
WHERE toLower(m.category) contains 'spam'
WITH ip, collect(m) AS spam_messages
RETURN ip, size(spam_messages) as spam_messages_size
ORDER BY spam_messages_size DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Simple and works perfectly. Is there a rule of thumb when to use `count()`, and when to use `size()` in situations where either could work?

Comment: They are not analagous. `count()` is an aggregation funciton. And `size() is a list function`. I'll will update the answer to illustrate the difference.